# Paypal custom logo and summary disappeared

Tags: paypal

Out of a sudden Paypal Express Checkout page doesn't show my custom logo and summary (cart items with prices and total). It used to be ok since 2012 or so... actually it was OK yesterday. Now I can see neither Summary nor My custom logo BUT...
the default landing page is "Login"
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC%2d3VC19181H76003451#/checkout/login

when I change it to "Billing" (/checkout/guest)  - I see both the logo and the summary (but that won't do as I need the same for "Login" )

a bit more details:
source code for /checkout/login:

```
"logo_url": "https://www.paypal.com/securecontent/image/536cd6ef4a1d818cc84ddd2123825b3802fcf1072c5c284e00b84af6f02bdd92bd51e6d2a7c2251cae7b28ce42a95a8e85841f0a48885aa59c2944166c43f61a4d82fd2df545843744f9634b9e237b9c"
```

but /checkout/guest source show a normal logo image url as it shoudl be:

```
      "logo_url": "http://empowercoachtraining.com/cart/logo.png",
```

what on Earth could this mean???
UPDATE:
    here is the screenshot:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

while studying the PP code I have found this:

```
    window.preload("get", "/webapps/hermes/api/pxp/xo_hermesnode_config?ctx.COUNTRY=CA", {
        "ack": "success",
        "data": {
            "treatments": [
                {
                    "experiment_id": 1275,
                    "treatment_id": 2918,
                    "treatment_name": "xo_hermesnode_vzero_fallback_treatment"
                },
                {
                    "experiment_id": 1215,
                    "treatment_id": 2775,
                    "treatment_name": "xo_hermesnode_ul_2fa_treatment"
                },
                {
                    "experiment_id": 1314,
                    "treatment_id": 3005,
                    "treatment_name": "xo_hermesnode_ul_safe_treatment"
                },
                {
                    "experiment_id": 1991,
                    "treatment_id": 4667,
                    "treatment_name": "xo_hermesnode_fraudnet_switch_treatment"
                },
                {
                    "experiment_id": 1953,
                    "treatment_id": 4572,
                    "treatment_name": "xo_hermesnode_hide_cart_logo_treatment"
                },
                {
                    "experiment_id": 1465,
                    "treatment_id": 3410,
                    "treatment_name": "xo_hermesnode_fraudnet_webview_treatment"
                }
            ],
            "tracking_tags": "qt=2378,2364,2410,2394,2861,2848,2852,4073,2859,4937,2918,5060,2772,2775,2976,3005,4667,2281,4572,3410,3363;qc=2622464,2623488,2622464,2623488,2622464,2622464,2622464,2621440,2622464,2621440,2621440,2622464,2621440,2621440,2623488,2621440,2621440,2623488,2621440,2621440,2622464;uqt=;uqc=;ot=;os="
        },
        "meta": {
            "calc": "d40a3098d0bfb",
            "rlog": "rZJvnqaaQhLn%2FnmWT8cSUtwSUe%2B7Jlw%2Be%2BCxP%2BU439qAjpsUs62YLodr1eS8%2By5PwuMWiiZPEOimvRWnD0WiCQ_15b0940c164"
        },
        "server": "XKL24UPATYtlVuYrnpFQxRZMkEyJVdcX_sRhuVJdh8Rxhu5v684m9kXZqga9i60W4Vr01Z1zaNXk-5HBH-DDvPyUj2ltwCj6uaJ6ww1RaL-EIMMXTDhy8hbnBc7H4JBTR126YKSIuLI8cCAXWLQ4esqQDmNfOe_L1g-lGcAKBKQP30Q5vGyhIXb3TW9tEeVja1q0XKfmvoqkLInRUM6nDWCHV7vZGPOwlgJPOI3kN7K_aORiqWTgfU8ySkp07lWp"
    }, "pxpConfig");
```

maybe Paypal has just implemented/testing a new filtering system to hunt fraudulent activities? ...

Comment: it shows your logo here though

Comment: Check this please: http://a5w.org/up/uploads/mike/2017-03-26/1490506665_pp_exp_chkt.png

Comment: I don't know exactly but looking at your screenshot it looks like the browser is blocking http requests. See when it shows your image the green lock goes gray that means non https resources are loaded. Try to host `http://empowercoachtraining.com/cart/logo.png` at a https location

Comment: tried both http and https (Paypal, by the way, requires HTTPS for images though I have had NO problems with having custom image headers and http) ...and, after all - why the cart's summary is not shown?....weird shit... how I hate such odd glitches.... arrgh... Thanks,man!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your SSL certificate has not expired. 
You may have to renew it.

Note: For those using CPanel with a SSL certificate issued by Let's Encrypt, you can check the expiration date by logging into CPanel and going to "Security > Let's Encrypt SSL".